# Python all_unique with a custom comparator function

Tags: python

In this code snippet:

```
import more_itertools

def eq(a, b): return a%2 == b%3 # just a placeholder

a = [1, 7, 13]
print(more_itertools.all_unique(a))
```

I would like to use `eq` function to compare elements of `a` instead of equality.  Is there a library function to accomplish that?

**EDIT**

The discussion was derailed by focusing on the non-commutative `eq` example in my original post, disregarding my *just a placeholder* comment next to it. In order to put it back on the tracks, consider:

```
def eq(a, b): return f(a) == g(b)
```

which is commutative and defines an equivalence relationship.

Comment: Can you tell us in words how that function should define uniqueness in a collection of things? It seems like a problematic definition of equality where `eq(8, 6) => True, eq(6, 8) => false` making it unclear what `all_unique` should mean with in put like `[6,8,8,6]`.

Comment: @Mark `eq` is just a placeholder, substitute by any non-trivial function of your choice. In this non-commutative `eq` example, results for your example would depend on implementation.

Comment: if you're trying to add a custom comparison method, you may be better served by making each of your values custom class instances with an `__eq__()` method containing your logic

Comment: @ti7 Good idea. Requires OOP style, but it will work.

Comment: `more_itertools.all_unique()` accepts a function... just do `more_itertools.all_unique(a, key=eq)` -- just check the docs: https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.all_unique

Comment: @ddejohn if you look at the function  proposed you will see why that won't work.

Comment: @ddejohn I tried before posting my question. `more_itertools.all_unique` requires a single argument function for `key=` parameter.

Comment: @Mark it looks to me like Paul is simply asking how to use custom comparators in the `all_unique` function.

Comment: @ddejohn Yes, that's what I'm asking about. I'm going to steal *custom* and put it in the title.

Comment: No @ddejohn his comparator function is non-commutative, which means a single key function won't perform the same way.

Comment: I understand that the function OP gave is not a valid comparator. I am simply answering the general question OP was asking, which is how to use custom comparators. Plenty of people have already demonstrated to OP why their proposed function won't work.

Comment: `eq is just a placeholder, substitute by any non-trivial function of your choice`. I think the problem is that to define a function to determine uniqueness, that function must define a equivalence relationship. One of the requirements for equivalence is symmetry which your example doesn’t have. Maybe something a variation of  `reduce` or `filter` would be a better fit here.

Comment: @Mark As other comments above, you are making the assumption that `eq` is supposed to be a proper equivalence. This is a straw man argument. My question does not require proper equivalence. The question is about substituting `__eq__` with `eq`, whatever the properties of `eq` are, non-commutativity and all.

Comment: If your question does not require proper equivalence, then you are not looking for a function that establishes uniqueness. Which means we don't know what `that` means in your question `Is there a library function to accomplish that?`.  As stated, I don't think your question is answerable.

Comment: Based on your edit, if your functions are symmetric (which is probably a more correct term than commutative), that means `f(a) == g(b)  and  g(a) == f(a)`.  By substitution , this means `g(a) == g(b)`, which mean you can just use the regular `key` parameter with `g()` (or `f()` by the same argument).

Comment: @Mark We are getting off the track again by focusing on the insides of the comparator function `eq`. Treat `eq` as a function with unknown implementation. BTW, the updated `eq` is commutative. That's what I want to pass as a parameter to some library function.

Comment: I'm going bow out @PaulJurczak. I think I've made my case that if this function defines an equivalence and is symmetric, then you should be able to do whatever you are trying to do with a unary function. Clearly you are after something else. Best of luck with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: In response to OP's comment below, here is a "pure" Python standard library implementation where the only custom function is the (not) equality checker:

```
from itertools import permutations

a = [1, 3, 7]

def noteq(t):
    return t[0] != t[1]

# unique if all permutations of element pairs are not equal
all(map(noteq, permutations(a, 2)))
```

Output:

```
True
```

---

If you don't mind implementing your own version of `all_unique` here is a relatively straightforward way to do it while enabling the use of a custom comparator function:

```
from operator import eq

def myeq(a, b):
    return a % 2 == b % 3

def all_unique(values, eqfunc=eq):
    for i, a in enumerate(values):
        for b in values[i+1:]:
            if eqfunc(a, b):
                return False
    return True

print(all_unique([1, 7, 13], myeq))
```

Output:

```
False
```

Comment: Sure, but my question was: *Is there a library function to accomplish that?*

Comment: Nice. I prefer `eq` vs. `noteq`, i.e. 
```
    def eq(p): return p[0] == p[1]
    print(not any(map(eq, permutations(a, 2))))
```
Code formatting in comments doesn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to just hash it with a set and then see if the length is the same!

```py
def all_unique(l):
    return len(set(l)) == len(l)
```

Comment: `set` uses a built-in equality, while I want to use a user defined one, i.e. `eq` in my post.

Comment: `set()` uses the equality of `__hash__`!

Comment: Yes, but I want to use a custom comparator function `eq`.